# Вывод числа с плавающей запятой на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода числа с плавающей запятой в коде:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char n;
    int k, i;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("color f0");
    cout << "Введите арифметический знак " << "\n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите значение k " << "\n";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "Введите значение i " << "\n";
    cin >> i;
    switch (n)
    {
    case'+': 
        k+=i;
        cout << k << "\n";
            break;
    case'-':
        k-=i;
        cout << k << "\n";
            break;
    case '*':
        k*=i;
        cout << k << "\n";
            break;
    case '/':
       k/=i;
        cout << k << "\n";
            break;
    case '%':
        k%=i;
        cout << k << "\n";
            break;
    default: cout << "Неверный арифметический знак \n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В строке `k/=i`, k должно являться типом данных `float` или `double`, однако сейчас является типом `int`. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилась часть числа после запятой?

Comment: Если нужна `k` типа `double`, то и объявляйте ее с этим типом

Comment: либо приводите int к float и сразу выводите результат (т.к. пытаться записать число с плавающей точкой в int - плохая идея): cout << static_cast<float>(k) / i << '\n';
C++ статически типизированный язык)

Comment: В дополнение к абсолютно правильному ответу выше хочу лишь добавить, что вам стоит почитать про явное и неявное преобразование типов. По этой теме много статей, но зато вам станет понятно, что `int/int=int`, а `double/int=double`. Да, из-за строгой типизации вы уродуете код static_cast'ами, но зато это дает хорошое преимущество. Как минимум в том, что вы всегда знаете что вы ожидаете и какой тип

Comment: @ComelnRage, насколько я понял, под сильной/слабой типизацией подразумевается другое. C++ слабо типизированный, это означает, что мы без проблем можем привести char к int, а в питоне, который строго типизированный, к примеру, мы сможем привести char к int, только если в char лежит цифра (да и '1'(char) он приведет к 1(int), а не к 49(int), как было бы в C++), в других случаях он не станет смотреть на ascii таблицу.

Comment: А что не так-то? Представьте себе калькулятор, который ничего не высвечивает дальше точки. Вот вы такой и написали. Хотите нормальный калькулятор? Используйте *не*целые числа, `double`.

Comment: У меня была проблема в том, что когда вводил ```float k```, в строке ```k%i```, и я не просто понимал, как задать тип ```float``` для ```k```, чтобы работала программа, но благодаря вам теперь разобрался, благодарю всех вас за помощь.

Comment: @HMS_TRINIDAD В питоне нет типа char, есть только строки. Причем юникодовые, а не а ASCII. Ну и странно называть язык с динамической типизацией и неявным преобразованием типов в контексте некоторых операций  языком с сильной типизацией.

Comment: @user7860670, но почему тогда питон называют ЯП со строгой типизацией? И почему Си - со слабой? Недавно начал интересоваться этим, если я что-то неправильно понял - было бы хорошо сейчас же это исправить. Вот только это уже совсем другой вопрос…